Change date input format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in Ruby on Rails
Good afternoon,
Im trying to change my input format date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy.
This is my code:
%= f.text_field :resolution_date,  class: 'form-control',  type: 'date', value: params[:incident].present? ? params[:incident][:resolution_date] : '' %>
As for now, I wasn't able to do so.

Use f.date_field instead of text_field. In general don't mess around with formatting date inputs - you're just going to annoy your users. Let their preferences decide how its going to be localized. The HTML date inputs expect YYYY-MM-DD as the value.

Can you try the strptime functionality of Date class?
Date.strptime(your date input, "%m/%d/%Y")
